# Jaxb Marshalling for newbies

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, marshalling

All I'm trying to achieve is simply to marshal to a xml file

**Contacto.java**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Contacto {
    @XmlElement
    public String nombre;
    @XmlElement
    public String telefono;
    @XmlElement
    public String email;
    @XmlElement
    public String direccion;
}
```

**Actividad.java**

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Actividad {
    @XmlElement
    public Calendar fecha;
    @XmlElement
    public String lugar;
    @XmlElement
    public String motivo;
    @XmlElement
    public Contacto participante;
}
```

**Agenda.java**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Agenda {
    @XmlElement
    public String nombrePropietario;
    @XmlElement
    public Actividad actividad;
    @XmlElement
    public Contacto contacto;
}
```

This is the **XML Schema** generated using JAXB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="actividad" type="actividad"/>

  <xs:element name="agenda" type="agenda"/>

  <xs:element name="contacto" type="contacto"/>

  <xs:complexType name="actividad">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="fecha" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="lugar" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="motivo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="participante" type="contacto" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="contacto">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="telefono" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="direccion" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="agenda">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="nombrePropietario" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element ref="actividad" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element ref="contacto" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="principal">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

And this is the Class where I try to instantiate some of the other classes and marshall their data to a xml file:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.lang.Object;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Contacto contacto = new Contacto();
        contacto.nombre = "John Doe";
        contacto.telefono = "911";
        contacto.email =  "johndoe@gmail.com";
        contacto.direccion = "742 Evergreen Terrace";

        Actividad actividad = new Actividad();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(2013,04,17,15,30,00);
        actividad.fecha = cal;
        actividad.lugar = "General Pico";
        actividad.motivo = "Reunion";
        actividad.participante = contacto;

        Agenda agenda = new Agenda();
        agenda.nombrePropietario = "John Smith";
        agenda.actividad = actividad;
        agenda.contacto = contacto;


        try {
            File file = new File("archivo.xml");

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Contacto.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // Salida
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(contacto, os);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(contacto, System.out);
/*
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(actividad, os);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(actividad, System.out);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(agenda, os);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(agenda, System.out);
 */
        } catch (Exception e) { //JAXBException e
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

The problem is it never generates the .xml file. I just need to solve this small issue, I know I probably face the problem not in the best way, but i'm stucked here.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Does `jaxbMarshaller.marshal(contacto, System.out)` print what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE #2**

Double check the `java.io.File` is being created where you think it is.  You can check this as follows:

```
File file = new File("archivo.xml");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

You may find marshalling directly to a `java.io.File` directly:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshal(java.lang.Object,%20java.io.File)

---

You need to close the `FileOutputStream` after the marshal operation.

```
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("archivo.xml");
    marshaller.marshal(config, out);
    out.close();
```

BTW you don't need all those `@XmlElement` annotations as by default all public properties and fields will be treated as mapped by default.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Comment: I closed the stream but still not getting the file.
I know I didn't need to use the @XMLElement (I forgot about them at first) but I still put them because I'm learning and to understand a bit more about JAXB. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer again! But Marshaling to a File directly doesn't do the job either. Sorry for bothering you with such a newbie problem.

Comment: @MarceloZárate - Are you getting a stack trace?  All these hints should be working for you.  Does the output to `System.out` work.

Comment: Now the file is created where it should be, but it is an empty file.